# Node.js - unexpected duplicate post rest call

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest, sockets, koa

Tech Stack:

- Angular 1.4 app-client, that POSTs to:
- Node 5.1 app-server (koa/es6 based framework), that POSTs to:
- Node 5.1 microservice-server (koa/es6 based framework), that calls:
- Oracle 11.x stored proc

We are having a strange issue that has been stumping our dev team for the last 2 days. We have noticed that a microservice POST rest call that initiates an Oracle stored-proc experiences a second ***identical*** (but unexpected) POST rest call approximately one minute after the first POST occurs (its a long running stored-procedure). We traced this duplicate call back to the app-server which is experiencing the same duplicate POST issue. Initially we thought that the culprit was bad logic in the Angular client however console logging and network analysis shows that the client only initiates one POST to its back-end. The second POST on the app-server seems to be self-initiated.

Here is the route-handler code on the app-server that handles the POST from the Angular client and subsequently POSTs to the microservice REST endpoint (the console logs will get spit out twice):

```
module.exports.quarantineActions = function*(){
    const opts = {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: transactionEndpoint+'/rest/quarantine-actions',
        json:true,
        body:this.request.body
    };

    console.log('POST to microservice initiated')
    const resp = yield request(opts);
    console.log('POST to microservice finsihed')

    this.status = resp.statusCode;
    this.body = resp.body;
};
```

I can also add that the app-server shows the following error whenever this duplicate call occurs (its not clear if its related):

> Error: socket hang up
>       at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:209:15)
>       at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:294:23)
>       at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:166:7)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:905:12)
>       at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:455:9)
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:369:17)

Our working theory at moment is that somehow a library in the mix (possibly koa-request or request) initiates a second POST if the first one does not receive a response. However where this is done and how to turn it off or extend timeout params is a mystery. At this point if anyone has had something similar happen and has any advice I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: How long does the process usually take to finish? Is the Angular app waiting the entire time for the POST to complete? Does the user need to know if the process completed successfully or errored out?

Comment: Dan - SP process can take anywhere from 10 seconds to several minutes depending on the user selections in angular app. Async listener in angular is supposed to wait for the process to finish and report sucess or failure back to user.

Comment: What is an "Async" listener? Are you polling, using WebSockets, or is it a single request and wait?

Comment: @Gatmando, having this same issue right now, trying to get a excel file from the user selected date, around 1 minute in wait, the request is called again... Are you using express.js too by any chance?

Comment: @FábioSantos we are using the Koa (v1) framework not express. We never did find a satisfactory way of solving the issue and instead have written a bit of a hack on the REST endpoint that receives the POSTs. On the affected route handler we instruct it to ignore subsequent identical POSTs that happen while the first process is still running. Its not pretty but it works. We simply have not had the time or manpower to explore further.

Comment: @Gatmando from our side the issue was on our AWS server, the timeout was set to 60 seconds, best of luck.